# How to make one dll out of two dll's?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, lib

First dll is coded via C++ (native) and a second dll is coded via C#.
The C# dll imports exported methods/functions from the C++ dll.

I did not find any hints to solve that problem.
I only found solutions that would result in more dlls.

I could also live with a solution that uses a .lib file derived from C++ code as long as my result is one single dll that does not need further files.

Comment: I suspect you do not yet truly understand the nature of how runtime linking works.

Comment: What is the underlying problem here? What is different about shipping one DLL file versus two?

Comment: The problem is: The proprietary license management system I use only accepts one single dll that has to be uploaded to the system. If it would be possible or easier to have a C++ .lib, this would also be sufficient.

Comment: And you cannot upload one of them and ship the other for free..?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I can only upload one single file, additional shipping or other additional measures are not allowed. Is there a way to solve this maybe via a C++ .lib file ?

Comment: _"The proprietary license management system"_ - Please elaborate... Can you name the service you're trying to use?

Comment: It is a company internal system, not officially available.

Comment: You can move one single file via drag and drop to be uploaded into a database, from where it is sent to the customer, once the license is activated. A fully automated process. That is the reason why it is not accepted to do additional shipping.

Comment: A .lib file is useless from the perspective of the C# perspective. And you cannot merge a C++ dll with a .NET DLL. This approach is a dead end.

Comment: @chrisk If it's an internal system then go file an issue in your Jira to tell them to fix/change it

Comment: If you have a internal system that only handles individual dlls you have a problem. Just about any non trivial .net application requires a bunch of dynamically loaded dlls. A common solution is to put all the files into a packet, see single file deployment, or just create a zip-archive.

Comment: When the C# assembly is used, it needs to use components already installed on the system, e.g. .NET. For example, the garbage collection needs to initialize to clean up unused memory, etc. C++ on the other hand, doesn't. Also, C# uses CIL (Common intermediate language), and C++ uses Assembly. Both of their instructions are not compatible with each other. I personally don't think you can merge unmanaged with managed DLL, e.g. C++ DLL with C# DLL. You can try to import a method from a C++ DLL inside of a C# DLL at runtime (there are tutorials online), or add two DLLs to a zip archive.

Comment: @Botje: That's not correct.  .NET-aware versions of the Microsoft linker (so anything in the last 2 decades) can link together C# .netmodule and C++ .lib into a single DLL.  You just have to do it at the appropriate stage of the build process; you can't wait until both are independently turned into DLLs.

Comment: @Ben if it is possible tu use a .lib, generated from my native C++ code and to statically link this to my c# dll, so that the result is a single .dll, I would be very grateful if you could give me some hints how to do that.

Comment: @chrisk: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/netmodule-files-as-linker-input?view=msvc-170   Using p/invoke in this case won't be as nice as the C++/CLI "It Just Works" technology, but I do know that p/invoke to an already-loaded DLL works just fine.

Comment: @BenVoigt _"...the Microsoft linker.."_ - hold up: I thought that depended on the CLR supporting multi-module assemblies, but only the full-fat .NET Framework 1.x-4.x supported that, while support was removed in .NET Core - consequently we now need to manually merge multiple modules from multiple assemblies into a single module with ILMerge separately from the VC linker... right? (VC's support for .NET is _weird_, maaaan)

Comment: @Dai: The linker's able to create the DLL.  If some versions of the CLR, which OP didn't even bother to mention in the question, can't deal with the DLL, that's a different problem.  But since OP proposes to only have native C++ code, there would be only one "assembly" or "module" in the .NET meaning of those terms.